# Java: How to open a webpage like Google in a JFrame/JPanel?

Tags: java, url, jframe, jpanel, html

I've looked around and everything always end with www.google.com looking like this: Webpage bug?

[image]

How can I open a webpage within a JFrame/JPanel and have it so that it looks like the normal whole page?

This is what I last tried:

```
 JEditorPane website = null;
 try {
    website = new JEditorPane("http://www.google.com/");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
website.setEditable(false);

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Google");
frame.add(new JScrollPane(website));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.pack();
}
```

Comment: JEditorPane ad JTextPane are not web browsers. The support limited HTML 3.2 and don't support any JS.

Comment: Swing doesn't support a full set of CSS and only supports HTML 3.2 and doesn't support JavaScript.  There are projects about which allow you to embed mozilla (FireFox) or IE within your application, but they will use heavy weight based components.  Another solution might be to look at the JavaFX WebView component

Answer (score 2):

As MadProgrammer suggested I took a look into JavaFX and found it was just what I wanted with this creating a basic webpage:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);      
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");
        //add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

    }
    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 500;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. :D